# jquery check for text node siblings

Tags: jquery

How do i check if there is text before an anchor element (it can be other elements, but usually anchor) or not?
Eg:
case 1:

```
<p> there is text here <a href="#">click here</a> and here</p>
```

in this case there is text before the an element, so the check should return true

case 2:

```
<p><a href="#">click here</a></p>
```

in this case it should be false

I tried few things this similar to :

```
if($(this).prev().nodeType==3)
```

but it does not work

Comment: you should provide more context about your posted code, what is `this`?

Comment: as mentioned by Amit Joki, this is "a" element. as you can see from the code, I am checking for the node just before "a" element in above cases

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `previousSibling` property of native DOM elements. Note that the indexer `[0]` is used to convert jQuery elemnent to native element, which supports `previousSibling`.

```
if($(this)[0].previousSibling.nodeType == 3){
   // it is textNode. Do something
}
```

Comment: this is checking for previous node of element, not its content

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't get you. `$(this)` refers to `<a>` I suppose

Comment: @AmitJoki: I am trying to understand the code. Why do we have the index for the element? let us say that I am performing the check on click, wont "this" have the element?
Also when I checked in my code, the if statement always returns true.